# Передача значения PHP переменной в xsl-шаблон

Tags: xml, php, xslt

Мне нужно передавать значения из php-скрипта xsl-шаблону.
Вот его фрагмент:

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="title">TITLE content</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="alt">ALT content</xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Т.е., вместо "TITLE content" и "ALT content" должны динамически подставляться значения переменных.
Непонятно, как. :(

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

У меня xml не содержит ни title, ни alt. Я добавляю их динамически через simpleXML:

```
$image=simplexml_import_dom($img);
$image->addAttribute('title', 'TITLE CONTENT');
$img = dom_import_simplexml($image);
```

Так вот, вопрос в том, как синтаксически передавать значение атрибута (т.е, что буквально подставлять вместо **'TITLE CONTENT'**, чтобы в XML было прописано **{$title}**? 
Или так и писать:

```
$image->addAttribute('title', $title);
```

?
Надеюсь, я правильно сформулировал вопрос (?).

Comment: так на вскидку у тебя 6 вопросов и ни одного принятого. так что ответа жди пару месяцев

Answer (score 2):

```
<img>
  <xsl:attribute name="title"><xsl:apply-templates select="img/@title"/></xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="alt"><xsl:apply-templates select="img/@alt"/></xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

Ну и XML должен иметь вид:

```
<img title="{$title}" alt="{$alt}"/>
```

Comment: спасибо, см. дополнение в вопросе плз.

Comment: Помоему ты сам же ответил на свой вопрос

    $image->addAttribute('title', $title);